# cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError) MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, nokogiri

I'm trying to setup a Rails project but unfortunately it fails when running `rails new railsapp`. I get the `in 'require': cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' (LoadError)` error.

To fix this, I did `cd railsapp` and changed the gemfile to `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8'` and ran `gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8` and `bundle i` but that still gives an error related to Nokogiri.

`require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)`

Also did the following things:
`gem uninstall nokogiri`

`bundle install nokogiri`

`bundle update nokogiri`

I have setup Ruby and Rails using https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur

`Rails 6.1.4.1`

`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]`

Comment: What is the output the the following: 1) `gem list nokogiri`; 2) `gem install nokogiri`?